# Page contents grows both up and down in bootstrap page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with Bootstrap and ASP.NET WebForms. I've built a basic site which outline is basically:

```
<body>
  <div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
```

and then heaps of content in various containers and rows.

What I've noticed is that the page grows from the center and outwards on the vertical axis, so if the page grows to where I need to scroll, parts of the page ends up out of bounds in the top (which is a bit icky since the navigation tends to be part of the stuff that disappears). The scrollbar in the web browser is already in its top-most position, so the content seems to be in some kind of "negative margin" space.

Is there a way to build the page ONLY grow downwards? I don't need the centered vertical alignment, it was simply there by default. I'll be just as happy with a page starting from the top and building downwards.

I hope someone understands my question here.

Comment: `<container>` is not a typical HTML element. Do you mean `<div class="container">`? you need a `.container` for a `.row` in Bootstrap... not a container element. Read the docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works)

Comment: Ah, my bad, I've corrected it

Comment: so that was just a typo in your question right? It doesn't fix your problem?

Comment: Correct, in the question only

Comment: Do you think you could provide a complete working code snippet of your problem? There shouldn't be negative space at the top, it should only grow downwards by default. Are you using `position: absolute;` or `position:fixed` on your layout? That might cause the issues you described, but its hard to tell without more code (HTML/CSS)